# Prevent script loading for specific route [Laravel]

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In my head section of my `form.layout.blade.php` I have the following:

```
<head>
   <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<head>
```

This is layout file is loaded before all pages are loaded. Is there a way to *not* load `main.js` for a specific route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use if statement like this. main.js will not load on this page

```
@if(!Request::is('subpage/url'))
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you! is there a way I can check the current Request? I'm not sure what to put as 'specific-route-here'

Comment: @timothyylim You can use this method like this: `Request::is('/home')`

Comment: that is the url of the page. (route name)

Comment: Hm. Doesn't seem to work. Can I log out the request just to debug?

Comment: the code is quite large but my url is like:  www.mydomain.com/subpage/url 
and @if(!Request::is('/subpage/url'))
doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I used for not loading scripts on all sites, is that I put script paths in variables in controllers, something like this:

```
public function show($id){
   $scripts[] = '/js/main.js';
   view()->share('scripts', $scripts); 
   return view('view', $someData);
}
```

This allows me to use this script only on a page I really need it, like this:

```
@if(isset($scripts))
    @foreach($scripts as $key => $value)
        <script src="{{mix($value)}}"></script>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Hope that this can lead you in right direction.

Comment: Very interesting, will definitely look into this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements

```
@if(!in_array(Route::currentRouteName(), ['route.name', ...]))

   <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

@endif
```